# Shrinkwrap with ray_cast isn't accurate

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, modifiers, bmesh

I'm trying to create my own similar Shrinkwrap-Modifier with raycast.
Unfortunately the result isn't accurate and I don't know why. It work's with Spheres, all other primitives are inaccurate.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

objA = scene.objects.active
objB = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(segments = 30, size = 100, location = objA.location)


bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

mesh_obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = mesh_obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
for vert in bm.verts:
    #vec = mesh_obj.matrix_world.inverted() * vert.co

    localA = objA.matrix_world.inverted() * objA.location
    localB = objA.matrix_world.inverted() * vert.co

    (location, normal, index) = objA.ray_cast(localB, localA)

    vert.co = location
```

[image: Torus]
[image: Cube]

Comment: the direction of casting is the problem,that's why you have many options for shrink_wrap modifier they differ in the direction they use for example nearest :  you have to find the closest point on mesh to the vertex and that's all (there's a function for that ), for projection i think they use the nearest face's normal